# How to create a new solution in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate without TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I installed Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate edition and it seems like there is no way to use it without connecting to TFS.  On the File menu, the only option is Connect to Team Project, but I just want to create a new Solution on my local machine.

I looked in Tools > Options > Source Control and chose "None" for the Current Source Control Plug-in but it had no effect on the menu options.

What am I missing? This is pathetic.

More Details:
Below is the list of installed products from the Help > About menu.  You can see that Team Explorer 2010 is one thing installed.  I stepped through the installation and I don't see a way to uninstall it or change it.

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
Version 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.0.30319 RTMRel

Installed Version: Ultimate

- Microsoft Office Developer Tools
- Microsoft Visual Basic 2010
- Microsoft Visual C# 2010
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2010
- Microsoft Visual F# 2010
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Architecture and Modeling Tools
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Code Analysis Spell Checker
- **Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Team Explorer**
- Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010
- Add Reference Dialog Plus!   1.0
- AlignAssignments   1.0
- AutoBraceComplete   1.0
- Crystal Reports Templates for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
- Document Well 2010 Plus   1.0.10916.0
- ExtensionUpdateCheck   1.0
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SharePoint Developer Tools
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.QuickAccess.Package   1.0
- PowerCommands for Visual Studio 2010   1.0

Comment: I'm not sure where you're problem lies...File > New Project doesn't allow you to create a new project/solution on your local machine? But then again, I've never worked with Team Projects so I may not be the best one to be answering this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From**: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/thread/8a390225-7d53-45d4-ba42-b1261a9e192e

Based on your description, it looks like that you have installed Team Explorer 2010 instead of Visual Studio 2010.

Team Explorer 2010 is a simplified Visual Studio Team System 2010 environment used solely to access Team Foundation Server services. It applies the similar shell as Visual Studio. However, we cannot create new projects via Team Explorer.
Thus, you can find only two options related to Team project when you go to File menu.

You can check Help Menu >> About Microsoft Visual Studio >> Installed products. You might find the following component:

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Team Explorer

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2008 Team Explorer installed but for 2010 it is Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate ver. 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel.

Comment: I guess you're right that Team Explorer 2010 is installed but I don't see any other way to install visual studio.  The ISO is en_visual_studio_2010_ultimate_x86_dvd so I am not sure why it defaults to the Team Explorer view.

Comment: Turns out that the new installation of 2010 was importing the settings of the previous version, 2008, which only had Team Explorer.  Reseting the environment fixed the problem. To change it go Tools > Import/Export settings > Reset > Choose preferred view.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, if you select the project management profile when you first start up VS, it won't allow you to create new projects. What doesn't make sense is that I selected c# profile. Still, the solution is the same as if i did select the project management profile. Reset VS with this comand line command:

```
devenv.exe /resetuserdata
```

Answer (score 2):

Open VS 2010 then go to

```
Tools > Select import/export settings > Import
```

and follow the instructions..